# How to get min date and max date from pandas df based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df as below:

| Name | Date1 | Date2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 199007 | 199010 |
| One | 199206 | 199206 |
| One | 199505 | 199505 |
| Two | 19880701 | 19880701 |
| Two | 19980704 | 19980704 |
| Three | 2020 | 2020 |
| Three | 2022 | 2022 |

Dates could be in the following format:
(yyyy-mm)
(yyyymmdd)
(yyyymm)
(yyyy)
(yyyy-mm-dd)

The requirement is - based on **Name** column -from **Date1** column find the minimum value and from **Date2** column find the maximum value.
Expected Data will look like this:

| Name | Date1 | Date2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 199007 | 199505 |
| Two | 19880701 | 19980704 |
| Three | 2020 | 2022 |

I have tried reading date1 and date2 columns as below:
df['date1']=pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])

But it throws error - month must be in 1...12 199007

when i run this line of code:
df['date1']=pd.to_datetime(df['date1'],format='%Y%m%d',errors=ignore)

but this is only ignoring error and nothing changes in the pandas df.

What i am trying to do here is first read date1 and date2 column as datetime format and then try finding min and max values for date1 and date2 column clubbing duplicate Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [.agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html). Then sort Name column from a custom list. Finally convert Date columns to datetime.

```
df = df.groupby("Name").agg({"Date1": "min", "Date2": "max"}).reset_index()

sort_list = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
list_series = pd.Series(range(len(sort_list)), index=sort_list)
df = df.sort_values("Name", key=lambda x: x.map(list_series)).reset_index(drop=True)

date_columns = [x for x in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains("Date")]]
for column in date_columns:
    df[column] = (
        pd.to_datetime(df[column], format="%Y%m%d", errors="coerce")
        .fillna(pd.to_datetime(df[column], format="%Y%m", errors="coerce"))
        .fillna(pd.to_datetime(df[column], format="%Y", errors="coerce"))
    )

print(df)

    Name      Date1      Date2
0    One 1990-07-01 1995-05-01
1    Two 1988-07-01 1998-07-04
2  Three 2020-01-01 2022-01-01
```